# Matlab - variable quantity of numbers in matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix. Rows in the matrix can reference between zero and and n other rows (though it's unlikely for it to be more than 10). How can I do this? Do I need to have a column that points to a linked list, or is there a more elegant and matlab-y way to do this?

Example:

```
123123 'JOHN' {1, 2, 3, 4}
154123 'DAN' {5, 123123}
```

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean? How do you want to handle that data or what do you want to do with it?

Comment: 123123 'JOHN' {1, 2, 3, 4}
154123 'DAN' {5, 6, 1, 123123}


Basically, every row will have a number, a string, and then a set of numbers.

Comment: As this pretty much looks like mixed data (i.e. a number, a string and a set of numbers = your references) this can be represented by a cell array array. A matrix only takes elements of the same type. Edit: but still, what is your question? How to represent this data structure? Edit: you could also use an array of structs/ struct array.

Comment: Among others, [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html), [structure](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/structures.html), or [table](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/tables.html).